# How to get autocomplete `super` on PyCharm

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, super

I'm searching for an autocomplete to super function.

Usually the super is something like:

```
super(MyClass, self).my_func(*func_args, *func_kwargs)
```

It there a shortcut/macro to have it auto completed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `ctrl+j` to list available macros and start typing `super` to select autocompleteon:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I hopes now it will be searchable